# How to check if a particular column contains "abc" in all the rows

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this part of my code :

```
function DeleteDuplicate() {

        var data = document.getElementById("CommitTable");
        var unique_data_Array = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
            unique_data_Array.push(data.rows[i])
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < data.rows.length; j++) {
            if (here)
            {
              work;
            }
```

I wan t my code to run through all the rows and look for the keyword "abc" in the first column.

I have tried to use `if(unique_data_Array[j][0] == "*abc*")` , but it is not getting executed properly.

Comment: use `.contains("abc")`? Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: you mean unique_data_Array[j][0].contains("abc")?

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: It is throwing an error ('0' is null or not an object)

Comment: I will need to see your html or sample of it

Comment: Please check edits , I have re-framed my question.

Answer (score 1):

You need;

```
if ( data.rows[j].cells[0].innerHTML.indexOf("abc") >= 0 ) 
{
  ...
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/KYfsL/).

Comment: hey , It is giving some random results if I use indexOf function .

Comment: I want to check if the word "abc" occurs more than once in the first columns of all the rows, I don't want to do anything with the indices.

Comment: I'd prefer `.textContent` over `.innerHTML`. +1 nonetheless

Comment: Hey , I realy think there is some confusion , I want to check if the word "abc" OCCURS more than once , not its index.

Comment: IndexOf() returns the value of the first occurrence of the string , not the number of times it has occurred.

Comment: @UjjwalVaish: You never said you wanted to count them??? Your question is "*how to check if it **contains** `abc`?*"!

Comment: ohh , sorry ! Thanks , I got the point of that code , if it finds "abc", it will return a value >0 , else will return -1, thanks all !! :)